# Azure Service Bus Relay Hybrid Connections load balancing

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebusrelay

Relay Hybrid Connections is one of the options to grant access to a RESTful web services hidden behind a firewall. I was wondering how the load balancing would work. There are multiple stateless instances of this web service:

- Would each of them register with the Relay service?
- Would I then have one Relay endpoint and many listeners behind it?
- How would the Relay service load balance?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would each of them register with the Relay service?
>
> Would I then have one Relay endpoint and many listeners behind it?

Per my understanding, since your web service is running under multiple stateless instances, you could construct the `HybridConnectionListener` instance on each of your web service instances for a better performance. As this official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/relay-hybrid-connections-protocol) states about **Listener interactions**:

> The Hybrid Connections service endpoint allows up to **25 concurrent listeners** on a Hybrid Connection.

> How would the Relay service load balance?

As the [Interaction model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/relay-hybrid-connections-protocol#interaction-model) mentioned about Listener interactions:

> If there are 2 or more active listeners, **incoming connections will be balanced across them in random order**; **fair distribution is not guaranteed**.

Comment: How would you then support a scenario where a set of connections that all need to communicate together but are load balanced to different listeners?  For a simpleexample, a chat application with 2 users, 2 listeners, each user connected (via load balancing) to a different listener?  If UserA sent a message to listenerA, the connection serviced by listenerA would have no idea how to send a message to userB... I've seen this solved with a backplane (think signalR), but that has its own set of problems.  Is relay not a good choice for supporting a scenario like this in a scale-out paradigm?